# Visual Studio 2015 RTM 1 update Error Interaction' exists in both 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2015

After updating visual studio 2015 to its Update 1 I get this error now when trying to build..

```
Error CS0433 The type 'Interaction' exists in both
'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity,
Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

the same thing with :

- BehaviorCollection
- EventTriggerBehavior
- ActionCollection
- InvokeCommandAction

The App works fine on another laptop that doesn't have the update 1 on Visual Studio 2015...

Comment: After restarting the laptop this issue went away...

Comment: Got the same error but restarting didnt fix

Comment: What reference did you add or update?